# WFDB Plot not working with code from documentation

Tags: python

I am starting an appplication with WFDB, (I'm new to the library) and it is giving me error messages with code I got straight from the documentation.

```
import wfdb
record = wfdb.rdsamp('mitdb/100', sampto=3000)
#annotation = wfdb.rdann('sampledata/100', 'atr', sampto=3000)
ann = wfdb.rdann('mitdb/100', 'atr', sampto=3000)
wfdb.plot_items(signal=record,
                #annotation=[ann.sample, ann.sample],
                title='MIT-BIH Record 100', time_units='seconds',
                figsize=(10,4), ecg_grids='all')
```

Gives the error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9ebb6f5d549b> in <module>()
      2                     #annotation=[ann.sample, ann.sample],
      3                     title='MIT-BIH Record 100', time_units='seconds',
----> 4                     figsize=(10,4), ecg_grids='all')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wfdb/plot/plot.py in plot_items(signal, ann_samp, ann_sym, fs, time_units, sig_name, sig_units, ylabel, title, sig_style, ann_style, ecg_grids, figsize, return_fig)
     99 
    100     # Figure out number of subplots required
--> 101     sig_len, n_sig, n_annot, n_subplots = get_plot_dims(signal, ann_samp)
    102 
    103     # Create figure

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wfdb/plot/plot.py in get_plot_dims(signal, ann_samp)
    126     "Figure out the number of plot channels"
    127     if signal is not None:
--> 128         if signal.ndim == 1:
    129             sig_len = len(signal)
    130             n_sig = 1

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Which is the plot_items code straight out of the documentation, so it should work, since the data I am using comes straight from their library. Is this a bug or am I missing something? I commented out the annotation code because that returns:

```
TypeError: plot_items() got an unexpected keyword argument 'annotation'
```

Which is confusing since this code is straight out of the documentation.

I tried to make a simpler command which came up with a different error code I can't figure out.

```
wfdb.plot.plot_wfdb(record=record)
```

With the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c3814c09f768> in <module>()
----> 1 wfdb.plot.plot_wfdb(record=record)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wfdb/plot/plot.py in plot_wfdb(record, annotation, plot_sym, time_units, title, sig_style, ann_style, ecg_grids, figsize, return_fig)
    405         ylabel, record_name) = get_wfdb_plot_items(record=record,
    406                                                    annotation=annotation,
--> 407                                                    plot_sym=plot_sym)
    408 
    409     return plot_items(signal=signal, ann_samp=ann_samp, ann_sym=ann_sym, fs=fs,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wfdb/plot/plot.py in get_wfdb_plot_items(record, annotation, plot_sym)
    421     # Get record attributes
    422     if record:
--> 423         if record.p_signal is not None:
    424             signal = record.p_signal
    425         elif record.d_signal is not None:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'p_signal'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is in demo #6 in https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python/blob/master/demo.ipynb.

I tried and it works very well.

```
# import library
import wfdb
# assign signals as ECG array from 0 to 1500 as your expected range, fields as other information
signals, fields = wfdb.rdsamp(r"C:\folder\MIT\100", sampto=1500)
# Plot with the array signals, fs as frequency (can be founds in fields['fs'], and title as an optional
wfdb.plot_items(signal=signals, fs=fields['fs'], title='Huy Test')
# Display it with the additional information
display((signals, fields))
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python Fixes these issues, took me hours to find the answer to this problem.

Comment: Can you be more explicit?