# The WFDB Plot-Demo results in TypeError

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I know that a similar question has been asked before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045540/wfdb-plot-not-working-with-code-from-documentation/52046782#52046782). But this seems not to reflect exactly my problem and it doesn't provide a solution either.

My Code is based on [this](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python/blob/master/demo.ipynb) plot-demo, provided by the offical WFDB project site.
However I'm getting an argument error.

Code:

```
from IPython.display import display
import wfdb

# Demo 1 - Read a wfdb record using the 'rdrecord' function into a wfdb.Record object.
record = wfdb.rdrecord('a103l', pb_dir='challenge/2015/training/')

# show the data
display(record.__dict__)

# plot the signals
wfdb.plot_wfdb(record=record, title='Record a103l from Physionet Challenge 2015')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-2-9722baf11c0e>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/home/david/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/scratch.py', wdir='/home/david/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches')
File "/home/david/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/182.4323.49/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
File "/home/david/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/182.4323.49/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "/home/david/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 15, in <module>
wfdb.plot_wfdb(record=record2, title='Record a103l from Physionet Challenge 2015')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wfdb/plot/plot.py", line 414, in plot_wfdb
figsize=figsize, return_fig=return_fig)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wfdb/plot/plot.py", line 120, in plot_items
plt.show(fig)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 253, in show
return _show(*args, **kw)
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I suspected a problem with my matplotlip but it works fine on its own.
I tried using python 3.6 and reinstalled the package. Also tried other wfdb plot examples with the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: You may inform whoever distributes "wfdb" that they have an error in line 120 of their `wfdb/plot/plot.py`, where it needs to be `plt.show()` instead of `plt.show(fig)`. Of course you may also fix this locally in your installed package.

Comment: I just filed [this issue](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python/issues/144) myself. You might also get around the error by not using PyCharm. It would be interesting which version of matplotlib you are using (`print(matplotlib.__version__)`).

Comment: So that worked. Changed `plt.show(fig)` to `plt.show()` as you said.
Thank you.
My matplotlib version is 2.2.3.

Comment: Tried the sample directly in the terminal and it works without editing `wfdb/plot/plot.py`. Any idea why PyCharm is making a difference here?

Comment: Providing an argument to `plt.show()` which is not `hold` is wrong. However all the matplotlib backends are currently very lenient and forgiving to further arguements - they are just ignored. PyCharm provides its own backend where it stricktly applies the arguments and hence errors out. I'm not too familiar with PyCharm, so you might be able to get it to work even within PyCharm by selecting a different matplotlib backend to be used.